# Changing encryption Algorithm in WSE 3.0

Tags: webservice-client

I am using a Java web services from a c# client.The web services is using WS-security.The request I am sending is using

Where as the server is expecting

When I tried changing it in the code I found that this property is a read-only property.

So how can I change this property?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the actual code from my WSE 3.0 client to change the encryption algorithm.

```
X509SecurityTokenManager objCertTokenManager = (X509SecurityTokenManager)SecurityTokenManager.GetSecurityTokenManagerByTokenType(WSTrust.TokenTypes.X509v3);
            objCertTokenManager.DefaultKeyAlgorithm = "RSA15";
            objCertTokenManager.DefaultSessionKeyAlgorithm = "TripleDES";
```